# Change Keyboard Layout in Turkish F Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard

I changed the keyboard layout of the Mac to Turkish F keyboard layout. But three keys (x,w,q) are not in their default places. I want to change the layout on my keyboard.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you added a layout that you downloaded somewhere?  Apple provides layouts called Turkish, Turkish qwerty, and Turkish qwerty pc, but not Turkish F.

Comment: What you mean by 'default places'? Places of all keys on the Apple keyboards on the their default places, but if you used to use PC/Win keyboards then their is a different for some keys. I am also Apple Turkish F keyboard user and typing at this layout about 10 or more year, and well know about ability to change layout by using Ukulele software, but in my opinion it is not right choice because its more right places for keys on Apple keyboard by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the free application [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele), you can change your keyboard layout into exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to **Turkish F-Legacy**. Apple with update macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 changed Turkish F layout, generally it's still Turkish F layout but as you aspected characters W,X,Q and some other moved to another places. I am analyze new layout and it is not bad in some point, but there is some little mistake, apple forgot asterisk '*' character, I don't know why but this annoying. And as I said generally it is not bad, but you can use old one if you want, just add F legacy, there is now two F layout from menu.